# Switch doesn't accept input until the second attempt

Tags: java, while-loop, switch-statement, do-while

I'm working on a project for a class and could use some help figuring out why my code is behaving the way it is.  The assignment is to prompt a user to input two integers and select an arithmetic operation to perform on them, while avoiding a "divide by zero" scenario.  Here's a section of my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program3 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    double operandOne;
    double operandTwo;
    char newLine = '\n';
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    //"input" is an object which calls for input from the keyboard.

        System.out.print("This program will request values for two operands ");
        System.out.println("and perform an arithmetic operation of your choice on them.");
        System.out.println(newLine + "Please enter a value for the first operand.");
        operandOne = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Thank you.  Please enter a value for the second operand.");
        operandTwo = input.nextDouble();

        // This section explains what's going on to the user and requests input for the operands.

        if ( operandTwo == 0 )
        {

            System.out.print("You will not be able to perform division if the ");
            System.out.println("second operand is zero!");
            System.out.println(newLine + "Please choose an option:");
            System.out.println("Type 1 to select a new value for the second operand.");
            System.out.println("Type 2 to continue with a value of zero.");

            // You can't divide by zero!  Are you SURE you want to use that number?

            int reallyWantZero = input.nextInt();
            do
            {   
                System.out.println(newLine + "You must type either 1 or 2 and press enter.");
                reallyWantZero = input.nextInt();
            }

            while ((reallyWantZero < 1) || (reallyWantZero > 2));
            {
                switch (reallyWantZero)
            {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println(newLine + "Please enter a new value for the second operand.");
                    operandTwo = input.nextDouble();
                break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println(newLine + "Okay, we will proceed.");
                    break;
            }
            }
        }
```

When I execute the code, I get the following:

"Please enter a value for the first operand.

1

Thank you.  Please enter a value for the second operand.

0

You will not be able to perform division if the second operand is zero!

Please choose an option:

Type 1 to select a new value for the second operand.
Type 2 to continue with a value of zero.

2

You must type either 1 or 2 and press enter.

2

Okay, we will proceed."

I don't understand why entering 2 to continue is not accepted the first time, but it is accepted the second time.  Can anyone help explain what's going on and how I can correct it?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

I modified my code to:

Ok, I understand what you mean, but it doesn't appear to work.  I modified my code to:

```
while ((reallyWantZero < 1) || (reallyWantZero > 2));
                {
                    System.out.println(newLine + "You must type either     1 or 2 and press enter.");
                    reallyWantZero = input.nextInt();
                }               
                switch (reallyWantZero)
                {
                    case 1:
```

but it still behaves exactly the same way.  Also, if I enter an invalid number, the program just hangs and doesn't return anything at all.

but it still behaves exactly the same way.  Also, if I enter an invalid number, the program just hangs and doesn't return anything at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because a `do...while` loop is always executed at least once

```
do
{   
    System.out.println(newLine + "You must type either 1 or 2 and press enter.");
    reallyWantZero = input.nextInt();
} 
while ((reallyWantZero < 1) || (reallyWantZero > 2));
```

It checks the condition after executing the body of the loop once. So it always enters this part of the code, which means the user will be asked to enter it at least twice. You need to use a while loop which will check the condition of the loop before entering it.

E.g.

```
while ((reallyWantZero < 1) || (reallyWantZero > 2)) {
    System.out.println(newLine + "You must type either 1 or 2 and press enter.");
    reallyWantZero = input.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: Wow, you're quick to respond!  :)
I'll add the modifications to the question.  Thanks.

Comment: remove the semi colon after the while statement look at my example above

Comment: Ha, that was it!  It's working as intended now.  Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just

```
while (reallyWantZero != 1 && reallyWantZero != 2) {
    System.out.println("enter 1 or 2");
    reallyWantZero = input.nextInt();
}

//do stuff here with that info
```

Comment: I'm a complete beginner, so I'm figuring this all out as I go.  :)